# Cocos2D Android app crash

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I'm developing Cocos2D android app, this is my 1st sample application. cocos2d-android.jar I downloaded and attached it in /libs folder. Here is my classActivity & logcat output

**CocosMainActivity** :

```
     CCGLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_cocos_main);



           getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
           getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

           mGLSurfaceView = new CCGLSurfaceView(this);
           setContentView(mGLSurfaceView);
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().attachInView(mGLSurfaceView);
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().setDeviceOrientation(CCDirector.kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait);

    CCDirector.sharedDirector().setDisplayFPS(true);
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().setAnimationInterval(1.0f/60);

    CCScene scene = CocosLayer.scene();
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().runWithScene(scene);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().pause();
}
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
     CCDirector.sharedDirector().resume();
}

 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
     CCDirector.sharedDirector().end();
}

 static class CocosLayer extends CCLayer{
        CCLabel label;
        CCSprite iconImage;
        public static CCScene scene(){
            CCScene scene = CCScene.node();
            CCLayer layer = new CocosLayer();
            scene.addChild(layer);

            return scene;
        }
        protected CocosLayer(){
            this.setIsTouchEnabled(true);

            //add label
            label = CCLabel.makeLabel("cocos2d Droid Label", "Droid Sans", 30);
            label.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(164, 240));
            addChild(label,0);

            //add image
            iconImage = CCSprite.sprite("ic_launcher.png");
            iconImage.setPosition(CGPoint.make(100, 100));
            addChild(iconImage,0);

        }

    }
```

**LogCat** :

```
 01-30 10:52:40.642: E/AndroidRuntime(664): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 75
 01-30 10:52:40.642: E/AndroidRuntime(664): java.lang.NullPointerException
 01-30 10:52:40.642: E/AndroidRuntime(664):     at   org.cocos2d.nodes.CCAtlasNode.updateBlendFunc(CCAtlasNode.java:168)
 01-30 10:52:40.642: E/AndroidRuntime(664):     at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCAtlasNode.<init> (CCAtlasNode.java:77)
 01-30 10:52:40.642: E/AndroidRuntime(664):     at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCLabelAtlas.<init>(CCLabelAtlas.java:40)
 01-30 10:52:40.642: E/AndroidRuntime(664):     at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCLabelAtlas.label(CCLabelAtlas.java:35)
 01-30 10:52:40.642: E/AndroidRuntime(664):     at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCDirector.setGLDefaultValues(CCDirector.java:593)
 01-30 10:52:40.642: E/AndroidRuntime(664):     at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCDirector.onSurfaceCreated(CCDirector.java:636)
 01-30 10:52:40.642: E/AndroidRuntime(664):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1494)
 01-30 10:52:40.642: E/AndroidRuntime(664):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

I h'v placed this "ic_launcher.png" in assets folder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_cocos_main); comment this line

Comment: and also place image "fps_images.png" in assets.